# How do I prevent Illustrator from creating thin strokes when I expand a pattern?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a pattern that was created using Illustrator's pattern making tool.

I applied it to an object.

I then scaled up the pattern 160%.

When I expand the pattern, it does not expand correctly. See screenshots here:

Original:

[image]

Expanded:

[image]

I am **not** talking about gaps in my patterns. I am talking about the **stroke weight not keeping its appearance when expanded in a pattern**.

Comment: See my updated question. This is not the same issue as seeing gaps in my patterns.

Comment: The pattern looks fine, it merely looks like it's scaled.  Did you check that the pattern itself is applied at 100% to the object?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Edit > Preferences > General, and **make sure the Scale Strokes & Effects** is selected. By default this is unchecked in Adobe Illustrator.

Now stroke weight will keep its appearance when expand your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Expand the pattern before applying it an object. It may or may not work to apply it to an object and then expand it (I've seen it work and not work).